# SDL iOS disable event pump

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, events, sdl

I have a question about the following SDL function:

```
void SDL_iPhoneSetEventPump(SDL_bool enabled)
```

The documentation says:

> Use this function to enable or disable the SDL event pump on Apple iOS.

Now in what cases is it required or recommended to use this function?

Answer (score 0):

This is useful when you don't want polling events to trigger any `CADisplayLink` you got added to the common or default runloops.

```
    self.displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(self.runTick(step:)))
    self.displayLink?.add(to: .main, forMode: .default)
```

If your polling or iterating over SDL2 events happen in here, it will trigger another callback.

```
       @objc func runTick(step: CADisplayLink) {
            //poll events. 
        }
```

Because of this SDL2 snippet:

```
  SInt32 result;
  do {
       result = CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, seconds, TRUE);
  } while (result == kCFRunLoopRunHandledSource);
```